# How to preserve NULL values in jQuery ajax POST sent to PHP script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

Suppose I have a PlainObject:

`formData: 
    completed: null
    limit: "10"`

Which I then use in an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: SomeEndpoint.php,
  data: formData,
}).done(function (response) { do stuff }
```

The POST value in SomeEndpoint.php receives all values as empty strings:

```
$completed = $_POST['completed'] ?? null; // ""
$limit = $_POST['limit'] ?? null; // "10"
```

How can I preserve the typing? What's the best way to validate typing if an endpoint validates that a variable is either NULL or an Int/Bool?

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery validation as 
validator - https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Options - https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/